# How to run DBCC CHECKDB when you cannot connect to database?

Tags: sql-server, dbcc

It appears that I have some file system issue that is preventing me from connecting to MS SQL Express 2008 R2 on my local machine. I receive this message when trying to connect:

[image]

Looking over the DBCC CHECKDB reference, it does not appear that I can run this command without being connected to the database. Any ideas of how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a look at some of the links on google for repairing a [corrupt master database](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=master%20database%20corrupt&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-gb:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&redir_esc=&ei=FP1xTqG-G9S18QPIpJGACg).